# Correct method of reducing the number of images created by WP and Woo together

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, images

I create my own WP&Woo theme and i have some doubts about the number of images that are generated by **wordpress** plus **woocommerce**

- Wordpress generate **4 sizes**
- Woocommerce generate another **3 sizes**

*So we have **7** generated images*

Its not hard to count that if we have a **eight thounsand products**, WP and Woo will generate **56 thousands images**!!! In my opinion it's a little disaster

I looking for a best solution for decrease that

**My 1st idea:**

Unset WP default images sizes with `intermediate_image_sizes_advanced` filter. I think it's not a best idea to remove default sizes. Example below:

```
function remove_default_images_size( $sizes ) {

    unset( $sizes['thumbnail']); 
    unset( $sizes['medium']); 
    unset( $sizes['medium_large']); // special hidden size
    unset( $sizes['large']);

    return $sizes;

} add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes_advanced' , 'remove_default_images_size' );
```

**or 2nd idea:**

Changing images dimensions in Woocommerce to identical with WP. We can do that via hooks. Example for thumbnails below:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_image_size_gallery_thumbnail', function( $size ) {
    return array (
        'width' => 150,
        'height' => 150,
        'crop' => 1
    );
} );
```

If i will do that,additional Woo images will not created because they will had the same sizes like WP native images.

All above method works, **but my question is**:

- which method will be better and more logical for project future?
- maybe is another method that i don't know?
- or maybe I should leave it as it is?

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the image sizes that you don't need.

```
function remove_image_sizes() {
    remove_image_size('image-name');
}
add_action('init', 'remove_image_sizes', 99);
```

Whilst the number of images is a factor, I'd also look at the image compression as this may be a big help in reducing the disk space required:

```
add_filter('jpeg_quality', function($arg){return 70;});
```

You will need to re-generate your images for this to take effect. Try the [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin. Alternatively, you can run a command line like [convert](https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php).

Here's a guide: https://www.howtogeek.com/109369/how-to-quickly-resize-convert-modify-images-from-the-linux-terminal/

One final method to remove the Wordpress default images is to set the dimensions to 0, as per [this article](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/delete-unused-image-files-wordpress/);